# Type of camera that is used in a double slit experiment

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment, camera

I need to know the type of camera that is used in a double slit experiment. Both with photons, and that with electrons? Can someone please answer. The type of camera that is used for observation. Is it a normal CCD camera or some other type of camera that captures electrons hitting the screen.

Comment: Please ask Google for some articles by researchers who have performed the double slit experiment, and see what types of cameras were used by the researchers.  It's really not appropriate to hope someone on StackExchange will do that rather easy work for you.

Comment: Dear Member, Thanks for the info. I have already sent it to several people with no vail. Just wondering is someone know it here.

Answer (score 3):

For single particles at a time:

[CCD cameras for photons.](https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/), **but** they just recorded the phosphor screen where the photons hit. These are particle experiments with particle interactions just recorded on screens. The same should be true for the [electron experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) , the cameras are used to take an image of a particle sensitive screen showing the passage of the deflected particle.

For [replicating Young's experiment](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/light/Lesson-3/Young-s-Experiment) any good camera would do to record the screen on which the pattern appears.

Comment: Anna - plenty of direct-imaging ccd cameras for electrons and photons are pretty common these days, no  phosphor used. Just direct excitation of carriers in the device.

Comment: DO YOU KNOW WHOM CAN I CONTACT REGARDING THE ELECTRON CAMERA.

Comment: Sorry, no. dr. Tonomura is no longer alive, and the Hitachi page https://www.hitachi.com/rd/research/materials/quantum/doubleslit/index.html does not talk about cameras. You could ask the company Hitachi to tell  you what camera gave the picturesm which they call macrographs.. in the video it is a monitor, not a camera, so maybe ther eis no camera in this experiment. Only the ccd in the photon experiment

Comment: Anna, the Hitachi monitor is for display, I looked at the display. I want to know the camera that is used for observation that changes from wave to particle. Any help will be appreciated. When get a chance, visit my site at www.balkans-interstar.com.

Comment: As far as I know there is no such camera, that can detect individual particles.The camera is the end recording a monitor display,in the electron experimemt, and a very sensitive screen in the photon, is all I have found out.

Comment: Thank you Anna. You have been very help full. Just wondering what causes the observer effect? I have an experiment that i want to perform, but running out of leads as to how to induce the observer effect. You can e-mail me at support@knsoftware.com. Will appreciate your help.

Comment: In the case of the double slit , for examplet the photon link, the "observer" are the geometry of the slits, and the interaction of the photon with the fields from the atoms/molecules of the side of the slits, the wavefunction of the set up gives to probability of the photon going one way or the other